# ExactTarget - FuelSDK-PHP, error: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, php, fuel-sdk

I am working in our ExactTarget FuelSDK-PHP integration over my local PHP server, that is a : PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli)

Also I have installed in my local PHP server the extensions of:
mcrypt :  Mcrypt v.2.6.8 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
openssl : OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
SOAP

We don't have any SSL certificate set up in our PHP server, I don't know if if it is needed... is it ?

In my SOAP connection I have this two values:

[location] => webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

[uri] => webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

Well and now calling the SOAP call for to get "all List" created into the "Exacttarget" platform.
we are doing this call running the FuelSDK-PHP GitHub example code from the file called: sample-list.php

And we are getting this error: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl#Retrieve.

Does anyone know what could be the reason? why?

Please tell me something for resolve this issue.

Thanks
Toni ll.

Comment: You definitely need to be using https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl .  Try that and report back.

Comment: Hi Timothy, ok I modify that value, but the error is still the same.